# How to optimise data inputs for my UIPicker and UICollectionView programmatically Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a total noob and learning iOS development programmatically and not with storyboards.

I have created two test controllers

1. Uses a UIPicker to allow selection of a Job Role using the scroll wheel
2. Uses a UICollectionView to all selection of a Job Role by tapping an Icon

I will probably use the UIPicker when a user registers and the UICollectionView to select a role to view its details as a Menu

I have created arrays in each controller to provide the required data for each

What I would like to do is be able to use a Data Model to hold eNums that hold the common data used by both.

I am not sure how to create arrays for my picker and collection views

I wanted to use enums as later on when a user has made a selection and I pass the output to my next controllers to act on I felt it would be good to do a switch on the selected item.

Appreciate any guidance and also if I am totally mad and going about it all wrong.

Cheers

**JobRoleMenuViewController.swift**

```
   import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class JobRoleMenuViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    var jobRoleLabel: [String] = [
        "Doctor",
        "Teacher",
        "Student",
        "Shop Keeper",
        "Fire Fighter",
        "I'm So Lucky!"
    ]
    
    var jobRoleImage: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "doctor")!,
        UIImage(named: "teacher")!,
        UIImage(named: "student")!,
        UIImage(named: "retailer")!,
        UIImage(named: "firefighter")!,
        UIImage(named: "astronaut")!
    ]
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView.register(JobRoleCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    // MARK: -
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jobRoleImage.count
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! JobRoleCell
        cell.categoryLabel.text = jobRoleLabel[indexPath.item]
        cell.categoryImage = jobRoleImage[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("DEBUG: Tapped cell at: \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}

// MARK: -

extension JobRoleMenuViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (view.frame.width - 2) / 3
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
}

}
```

**JobRoleCell.swift**

Please note: in the below code centerX and anchor are extensions I have created in Extensions.swfit so I can reuse across all code

```
import UIKit

class JobRoleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    var categoryImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            guard let categoryImage = categoryImage else { return }
            imageView.image = categoryImage
        }
    }
    
    let categoryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.tintColor = .black
        return label
    }()
    
    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        return iv
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Lifcycle
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 40, paddingLeft: 40, paddingBottom: 40, paddingRight: 40)
        
        addSubview(categoryLabel)
        categoryLabel.centerX(inView: self)
        categoryLabel.anchor(bottom: bottomAnchor)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }    
}
```

**JobRolePicker.swift**

```
import UIKit

class JobRolePickerController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    let jobRolePickerData: [String] = [
        "Doctor",
        "Teacher",
        "Student",
        "Shop Keeper",
        "Fire Fighter",
        "Astronaut"
    ]
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let picker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
        picker.delegate = self as UIPickerViewDelegate
        picker.dataSource = self as UIPickerViewDataSource
        self.view.addSubview(picker)
        picker.center = self.view.center
    }
    
    // MARK: - PickerController
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return jobRolePickerData.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let row = jobRolePickerData[row]
        return row
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        
        //        let jobRoleSelected = jobRolePickerData[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        print("DEBUG: Tapped cell at: \(jobRolePickerData[row])")
    }
}
```

I would like to try and use this to hold the data and share across all that need it and also use this to switch the outputs of both JobRoleMenuView and JobRolePickerView

**Job.swift**

```
import Foundation

enum JobRole: Int {
    //enum TradeType: CaseIterable {
    case doctor
    case teacher
    case student
    case retailer
    case fireFighter
    case astronaut
    
    var JobTitle: String {
        switch self {
        
        case .doctor:
            return "Doctor"
        case .teacher:
            return "Teacher"
        case .student:
            return "Student"
        case .retailer:
            return "Shop Keeper"
        case .fireFighter:
            return "Fire Fighter"
        case .astronaut:
            return "Fly me to the Moon"
        }
    }
    
    var JobImage: String? {
        switch self {
        
        case .doctor:
            return "doctor"
        case .teacher:
            return "teacher"
        case .student:
            return "student"
        case .retailer:
            return "retailer"
        case .fireFighter:
            return "firefighter"
        case .astronaut:
            return "astronaut"
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have the following screens and currently in debug window it prints out whatever is selected on each

[JobRoleMenuScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nLcb.png)

[JobRolePickerScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlgvz.png)

Comment: I know you said you're learning iOS development without storyboards, but I would recommend you check them out when you get the chance (if you're willing). They make life a lot easier.

Comment: Alex, Many thanks, I did have a look at them and even completed an iOS course on Udemy however I just did not get excited about them. I then did some other courses on Udemy that were without storyboards and i preferred that style. I learnt a lot quicker without storyboards. It seems my head works better when everything is in front of me in code that i can manipulate. I might try it again later on. I also want to look at SwiftUI as I guess that might be the future? It's just a hobby for me. I appreciate you taking the time to offer advice. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to storyboards vs. code, I generally find working with code to be cleaner and quicker. Especially when there isn't a complicated design to work out by code. Even if I wanted to set up my entire app graphically, I generally work with View Controllers attached to their own Xib files so as to avoid having a super large storyboard that becomes annoying to work with as it gets too large.

With regards to your question, if I understood correctly you just want to use your enum to source your picker and your collection view, rather than having to set the information manually each time. You were quite close (you commented out the conformance to the `CaseIterable` protocol).

I made some adjustments to your code:
For the enum I conformed to `CaseIterable` which allows you to access a property called `allCases` on the enum. This just returns all your cases in an array. I also added a variable to the enum that directly provides you with the image saved. I'm force unwrapping it (!) because the image should be there 100% of the time. So I'm not worried of it ever being nil. I also added a `numberOfItems` variable but this could easily be replaced with `allCases.count`. Anyway, either one of these will allow your `numberOfItemsInSection` to automatically reflect the amount of JobRoles you have.

```
enum JobRole: Int, CaseIterable {

    case doctor
    case teacher
    case student
    case retailer
    case fireFighter
    case astronaut

    static var numberOfItems: Int {
        return allCases.count
    }

    var image: UIImage {
        return UIImage(named: imageString)!
    }

    var jobTitle: String {
        switch self {
        case .doctor:
            return "Doctor"
        case .teacher:
            return "Teacher"
        case .student:
            return "Student"
        case .retailer:
            return "Shop Keeper"
        case .fireFighter:
            return "Fire Fighter"
        case .astronaut:
            return "Fly me to the Moon"
        }
    }

    var imageString: String {
        switch self {
        case .doctor:
            return "doctor"
        case .teacher:
            return "teacher"
        case .student:
            return "student"
        case .retailer:
            return "retailer"
        case .fireFighter:
            return "firefighter"
        case .astronaut:
            return "astronaut"
        }
    }
}
```

For the cell, I just changed the name of the image view and added a property called `jobRole` of type `JobRole`. Whenever this property is set, the label and the image view should automatically be updated.

```
class JobRoleCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var jobRole: JobRole! {
        didSet {
            categoryLabel.text = jobRole.jobTitle
            categoryImageView.image = jobRole.image
        }
    }

    private let categoryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.tintColor = .black
        return label
    }()

    private let categoryImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        return iv
    }()

    // MARK: - Lifcycle
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(categoryImageView)
        categoryImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 40, paddingLeft: 40, paddingBottom: 40, paddingRight: 40)

        addSubview(categoryLabel)
        categoryLabel.centerX(inView: self)
        categoryLabel.anchor(bottom: bottomAnchor)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then for your Data source providers (I only did the collection view but it should be easy to follow for the picker view):

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return JobRole.numberOfItems
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! JobRoleCell
    cell.jobRole = JobRole.allCases[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

So whenever you dequeue a cell or row for the picker, you can just use the indexPath to retrieve which Job Role you want assigned to that cell. Then you can remove the manual declarations you've made and have the enum provide you with all the necessary information for your cells (being the title, and the necessary image).